# how to reduce line number with passing parameter to static constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I know parameters cant pass to static constructor. But I am using this static class with parameters hence I initialize a variable I have to duplicate lines for each useage of this class functions

here is my logger class(it uses log4net, but its not in case):

```
public static class Logger
    {
        private static ILog log  {get; set;}
        static Logger()
        {
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }
        public static void Error(object msg, string userip)
        {

            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] = userip;
            if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                log.Error(msg);
            }
        }
        public static void Error(object msg, string userip, Exception ex)
        {
            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] = userip;

            if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                log.Error(msg, ex);
```

as you think I have to add custom "ClientIp" field for all kind of log methods. but I dont want to repeat

> log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] = userip;

line for each method 
I wish I can edit the constructor like this:

```
static Logger()
            {
                log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] = userip;
                log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            }
```

but I cant pass parameter to static constructor.. any advice ?

Comment: Just create a static property and set that at the beginning something like `public static string UserIP {get;set;}`

Comment: Where does the userip parameter come from? Does it not vary each time it is called?

Comment: @CallumLinington this is what I am trying now but in a bit trouble with httpcontext.current.. give me some time

Comment: @Chris yes its request owner ip address

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Initialize` method which you will call only once: at startup. Pass in the variables you need to set only once. In all subsequent calls, you can reuse those values.

Comment: Can you elaborate your post ?